# Splitting Maps by Peter Freyd

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I am trying to read “Abelian Categories” of Peter J. Freyd. On page 59, I was working on the “Splitting maps”-lemma in an abelian category, see the text in the picture. To prove the existence of the map $B_{23} \longrightarrow B_{22}$ such that $B_{23} \longrightarrow B_{22} \longrightarrow B_{23} =1$, Freyd suggests to apply the nine-lemma on the diagram shown in the picture (this diagram is commutative).

The nine lemma says that if the three columns and the middle row are exact, then top row is exact if and only if the bottom row is exact. However, in the given diagram the left column and the bottom and middle row are exact, so I do not see how to use the nine-lemma. My first thought was to take $B_{13} = B_{23}$ which makes the right column exact, but I still need the exactness of the middle column. Can anyone help me with this problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $ B_{12} $ and $ B_{13} $ aren't actually given in the hypotheses, so you can just take whatever you want (let's just say Freyd's hint isn't very clear on this).

You noticed that you can just take $ B_{13} = B_{23} $ to make the right column exact, but you can actually follow the same reasonning to have the middle one exact as well: it is exact iff. $ B_{12} \rightarrow B_{22} $ is the kernel of $ B_{22} \rightarrow B_{21} $, so just let $ B_{12} = \mathrm{Ker}(B_{22} \rightarrow B_{21}) $.

Now that we've properly filled the diagram (the top arrow $ B_{12} \rightarrow B_{13} $ is just the composite through $ B_{22} $), you can apply the nine lemma and get the result.